# Firebase no guarda nada

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

**Hola coders!**
Tengo una situación a la cual no puedo hallar solución: Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con Vue CLI y firebase. Tengo un formulario de registro el cual es funcional, pero a la hora de escribir datos en firestore no guarda nada.

No se muestra ningún error en consola y he visto algunos sitios donde enseñan a realizar la conexión y no veo algo distinto de lo que yo tengo.

Les dejo mis archivos para ver si tienen alguna sugerencia:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import * as firebase from "firebase"

Vue.config.productionTip = false

const configOptions = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAkUyYSxQq5g5DB6h_LgfG2lC7JzgIDHWw",
  authDomain: "t-panel-eccf9.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://t-panel-eccf9.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "t-panel-eccf9",
  storageBucket: "t-panel-eccf9.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "132805805270",
  appId: "1:132805805270:web:36b4b43a9b0829fc34b577",
  measurementId: "G-PF2ESSB4X8"
};

firebase.initializeApp(configOptions);

export const db = firebase.firestore()

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import Banner from '@/components/AuthScreens/Banner';
import firebase from "firebase";
import db from "firebase";

export default {
  name: 'signup',
  components: {
    Banner
  },

  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        inputRegisterEmail: "",
        inputRegisterPassword: "",
        inputRegisterName: "",
        inputRegisterLastName: ""
      },
      error: null
    }
  },

  methods: {
    submit() {
      firebase
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.form.inputRegisterEmail, this.form.inputRegisterPassword)
        .then(data => {
          db.collection("cities").doc("LA").add({
              name: "Los Angeles",
              state: "CA",
              country: "USA"
            })
            .then(function () {

            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              alert(error)
            });
          data.user.updateProfile({
              displayName: this.form.inputRegisterName + ' ' + this.form.inputRegisterLastName
            })
            .then(() => {
              //Code here

            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
          this.error = err.message
        })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

El primer código es main.js y el segundo es el apartado de script de mi archivo signup.vue

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada te hace falta importar el modulo `firebase/firestore` el cual no veo por ningún lado de tu código. Además de que tienes mal estructurado tu código

Tu primer código debería verse así:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Y en el segundo código que muestras estas importando dos veces el mismo módulo. Además te hace falta el modulo `firebase/auth'. En fin tu código es un desastre, parecen huevos revueltos(aunque son muy ricos xd)

Y el segundo código debería verse así

```html
<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import Banner from '@/components/AuthScreens/Banner';
import * as firebase from "firebase/app" // así para evitar importar todos los módulos de firebase
import "firebase/firestore" // con esto es mas que suficiente para usar la función 'firebase.firestore()'
import "firebase/auth"

const configOptions = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAkUyYSxQq5g5DB6h_LgfG2lC7JzgIDHWw",
  authDomain: "t-panel-eccf9.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://t-panel-eccf9.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "t-panel-eccf9",
  storageBucket: "t-panel-eccf9.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "132805805270",
  appId: "1:132805805270:web:36b4b43a9b0829fc34b577",
  measurementId: "G-PF2ESSB4X8"
};

firebase.initializeApp(configOptions);

const db = firebase.firestore()

export default{
    name: 'signup',
    components:{
        Banner
    },

    data(){
        return{
            form:{
                inputRegisterEmail: "",
                inputRegisterPassword: "",
                inputRegisterName: "",
                inputRegisterLastName: ""
            },
            error: null
        }
    },

    methods:{
        submit(){
            firebase
            .auth()
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.form.inputRegisterEmail, this.form.inputRegisterPassword)
            .then(data => {
                db.collection("cities").doc("LA").add({
                    name: "Los Angeles",
                    state: "CA",
                    country: "USA"
                })
                .then(function() {

                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    alert(error)
                });
                data.user.updateProfile({
                    displayName: this.form.inputRegisterName + ' ' + this.form.inputRegisterLastName
                })
                .then(() => {
                    //Code here

                })
            })
            .catch(err => {
                this.error = err.message
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Me arroja el siguiente error: **firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.collection is not a function.** Y sigue sin escribir nada en Firestore, los uduarios se siguen registrando sin problemas pero ahora sigue sin escribir además de que arroja ese error

Comment: Intentalo sin el atributo `type="module"`

Answer (score 0):

**Solucionado**
El error lo solucioné agregando **vue-firestore**. Les dejo el enlace en el que me basé por si le ayuda a alguien: https://alligator.io/vuejs/vue-cloud-firestore/